# how to figure out the type of template parameters using VS Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I am dealing with the heavily templated code and now need to figure out the type of template parameters.

In the following code that I simplified, How could you debug to find out what type each **T** is depending on main() that will initiate the A with int, double, or any other type.

```
template <class T>
class A // 1
{
public:
    typedef T Type;
};

template <class T>
class A<T*> // 2
{
public:
    typedef T Type;
};

template <class T> 
class A<T**> // 3
{
pbulic:
    typedef T Type;
};
```

I tried using **Watch** window but I don't think it can help me know what T's actual type is.

If T is int*, It will be the best for me to see the code in a instatiation form of the templated code that is something that goes like;

```
 class A // 1
 {
  public:
    typedef int* Type;
 };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you want, but (even in creaky old MSVS 2003) the Watch (or Auto) window does this nicely for me via the "Type" column:

[image: MSVS 2003 Auto window]

Note that within a program `T` could take many different types for different instantiations (e.g. I have three just in my little program in the picture), so it doesn't make sense to ask what type  `T` is outside the context of a specific instantiation.

If you are stepping through a method of a templated class, as well as checking the type of `this` in the Watch window, you can see it in the call stack:

[image]

Comment: How kind of you! Thank you very much!